# Not able to install Google Pay module(unboundcommerce/module-googlepay)

Tags: magento2, module, payment-methods, composer, installer

As per the requirement I need to integrate Google Pay in my Magento 2 site. But I am getting an error added below.

Command

> php -dmemory_limit=6G vendor/bin/composer require unboundcommerce/module-googlepay 1.1.1

also tried with

> php -dmemory_limit=6G vendor/bin/composer require unboundcommerce/module-googlepay:v1.1.1

But getting same error message

> Could not find a matching version of package unboundcommerce/module-googlepay. Check the package spelling, your version constrai
> nt and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).

[image]

Magento Version : 2.3.5-p1

Composer : 1.10.22

Module URL : [unboundcommerce/module-googlepay](https://marketplace.magento.com/unboundcommerce-module-googlepay.html)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

try

```
unboundcommerce-public/module-googlepay
```

isnstead of

```
unboundcommerce/module-googlepay
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use following command:

```
composer require unboundcommerce/module-googlepay:1.1.1
```

or

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G vendor/bin/composer require unboundcommerce/module-googlepay:1.1.1
```

Comment: Thak you for your reply, I tried the command in both Composer 1 and 2, but getting same error. I have added a screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 0):

composer require unboundcommerce/module-googlepay:1.1.1
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Continue as root/super user [yes]?
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update unboundcommerce/module-googlepay
Loading composer repositories with package information
In Laminas\DependencyPlugin\DependencyRewriterV2::onPrePoolCreate
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires unboundcommerce/module-googlepay 1.1.1 -> satisfiable by unboundcommerce/module-googlepay[1.1.1].
- unboundcommerce/module-googlepay 1.1.1 requires firebase/php-jwt 5.0.0 -> found firebase/php-jwt[v5.0.0] but the package is fixed to v5.4.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Answer (score 0):

please cross-check the package name.

https://packagist.org/packages/unboundcommerce-public/module-googlepay

you are executing the composer command with the wrong package name

please use: `composer require unboundcommerce-public/module-googlepay`

instead of `composer require unboundcommerce/module-googlepay:1.1.1`

Thanks